# The Maximum Singular Value of a Certain $\{1,-1\}$-Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have a $16$-dimensional real symmetric matrix with entries in $\{1,-1\}$.

$11$ of the rows are pairwise orthogonal, so are the remaining $5$ rows. But the two orthogonal sets are not necessarily pairwise orthogonal. In other words our matrix has two orthogonal sub-matrices, one $11$ by $16$ and the other $5$ by $16$.

What can we say about the maximum singular value (upper bound) of this matrix?

Comment: what happens with a 4 by 4 symmetric matrix of $0,1,-1$ with three orthogonal rows? Or two pair orthogonal rows?

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit. The matrix is of 1,-1 entries. No zeros.

Comment: and the analogous problems for 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 or 4 by 4 ????

Comment: (Edit:Also the matrix is not positive definite, it is symmetric). I'm thinking about your question.

Comment: So as an example I take the matrix with rows: {1,1,1,1},{1,-1,1,1},{1,1,-1,1},{1,1,1-1}. And the determinant of this is $-8$.

Comment: And the maximum singular value is $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: and what does that say about my question? @WillJagy?

Comment: @JamesSmithson, In your 4x4 example, all four rows are orthogonal.  What if rows 3 and 4 were $\{-1,-1,-1,-1\},\{-1,1,-1,-1\}$?

Comment: in my example the first row is not orthogonal with respect to other rows. So I always have a 2 by 2 non-orthogonal submatrix. In your example the matrix would not be symmetric so It wouldn't concern my question. @Darrell

Comment: a 2 by 4 orthogonal matrix*

Comment: it is also possible to have all four rows orthogonal, the square is four times the identity matrix, so all singular values are $2.$ So, for $n=4,$ we can partition as 4+0 or 3+1. My hand calculations say 2+2 is not possible, probably worth checking that by computer. Note that, since you deleted the $0$ entries, orthogonal pairs of rows are impossible in odd dimension. Note, by the way, for symmetric real matrices the singular values are just the absolute values of the eigenvalues. Meanwhile, wonder what partitions are possible in 6 by 6, (easy to program) and whether 11+5 is possible in 16